# PHP MySQLi bind param for array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having problems with a PHP script that returns some info based on a supplied array of identifiers (MAC addresses).

It gives me a 500 unspecified error.

```
if (!isset($_POST['macs'])) {
    echo 'Please enter mac addresses!';
    die;
}

$mysqli = new mysqli("x", "x", "x", "x");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_error)
    die("$mysqli->connect_errno: $mysqli->connect_error");

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

/* create a prepared statement */

$query = "SELECT username, mac FROM user WHERE mac IN (" . str_repeat("?,", count($_POST['macs']));
$query = rtrim($query, ",");
$query = $query . ')';

if ($mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), array_merge(array('s'), $_POST['macs']));

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['username'];
    }

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}


mysqli_close($link);
```

This is what I'm posting via the Postman Chrome app:

```
macs[0] = 'F0:72:8C:F3:B5:66'
macs[1] = 'FA:72:8C:F3:B5:66'
```

Can anyone at least hint me at what's causing the problem. I'm guessing it's the `call_user_func_array` call but, I'm unsure of what's the actual problem.

Comment: what does your PHP error log say?

Answer (score 0):

**// If you bind array-elements to a prepared statement, the array has to be declared first with the used keys:**

Coming to the problem calling mysqli::bind_param() with a dynamic number of arguments via call_user_func_array() with PHP Version 5.3+, there's another workaround besides using an extra function to build the references for the array-elements. 
You can use Reflection to call mysqli::bind_param().

Example:

```
<?php 
$db     = new mysqli("localhost","root","","tests"); 
$res    = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO test SET foo=?,bar=?"); 
$refArr = array("si","hello",42); 
$ref    = new ReflectionClass('mysqli_stmt'); 
$method = $ref->getMethod("bind_param"); 
$method->invokeArgs($res,$refArr); 
$res->execute();
```

for more
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#104073